# Parsing data between different activity

Tags: android, json

Hello friend i am doing one project, in this i have to retrieve the data from json and display it in listview on item click it has to go for next activity and display a large image and data in tab activity. how to parse the data to tab activity ta1 tab2 and tab3. Also to the image view. I am fetching all the data in my first activity only. now i am trying to send those data to the next activity.

this is my json code.

```
if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONArray arrJsonArray=new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Car_Car data1=new Car_Car();

                        data1.setId(object.getString("ID"));
                        Log.d("id",data1.toString());
                        data1.setTitle(object.getString("title"));

                        JSONObject image1 = object.getJSONObject("featured_image").getJSONObject("attachment_meta").getJSONObject("sizes").getJSONObject("thumbnail");
                        data1.setImage(image1.getString("url"));
                        JSONObject image2 = object.getJSONObject("featured_image").getJSONObject("attachment_meta").getJSONObject("sizes").getJSONObject("medium");
                        image2.getString("url");
                        data1.setModel(object.getString("bm_model_no"));
                        data1.setPrice(object.getString("bm_car_price"));
                        data1.setYear(object.getString("bm_year_of_manufacture"));

                        CarList.add(data1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all of data that you receive on first actvity to second activity then you can use following code to send data through Intent

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", iddata);
        intent.putExtra("title", titledata); 
        startActivity(intent);
```

Code To Receive Data that sent through Intent in SecondActivity

```
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String id=b.getString(id);
```

If you want all of data that you receive on first actvity to Entire Application then you can user SharedPreferences.
Code To Save data in SharedPreferences

```
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("id", "iddata");  
        editor.commit();
```

Code To get Data from SharedPreferences

```
         String id=pref.getString("id", null);
```

Comment: how to get reference for image view and set the image view in second activity

Comment: you can't pass the reference of imageview from one activity to another activity. you can do one think if you have image path then you can pass the image path using intent or SharedPreferences to anotheractivity and using this pass you can set image in anotheractivity.

Comment: Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String path=b.getString(filepath);imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways to achieve that :

**Method 1:** 
Use static class setter and getter method:

create static class and set values from first activity and get value from second activity

**Method 2:**

Post your values through the intent

**Method 3:**

Use database to store data from one activity and get data from other activity

**Method 4:**

Use Shared preference